# Magento 2.2.5 URL Rewrites - Duplicate entry 'myurl' for key 'URL_REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_STORE_ID'

Tags: url-rewrite, magento-2.2.5

I am seeing this error when trying to perform a search/replace on the url_rewrites table:

```
UPDATE url_rewrite SET request_path = REPLACE(request_path, '.html/', '/');

SQL Error (1062): Duplicate entry 'myurl' for key 'URL_REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_STORE_ID'
```

*(I need to do this because my URLs are messed up and being formatted like this:
category1/category2.**html**/category3/product-url)*

I understand that there are unique constraints on this table but when I search for the offending rewrite that is given in the error message it is not found.

```
SELECT * FROM url_rewrite WHERE request_path LIKE '%myurl etc etc%';
```

So there is my confusion! How can it be a duplicate if there is not one there already?!

(Magento 2.2.5)

Answer (score 0):

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE url_rewrite;
```

Output:

```
| url_rewrite | CREATE TABLE `url_rewrite` (
  `url_rewrite_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Rewrite ID',
  `entity_type` varchar(32) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Entity type code',
  `entity_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Entity ID',
  `request_path` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Request Path',
  `target_path` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Target Path',
  `redirect_type` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'Redirect Type',
  `store_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Store ID',
  `description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Description',
  `is_autogenerated` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'Is rewrite generated automatically flag',
  `metadata` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Meta data for url rewrite',
  PRIMARY KEY (`url_rewrite_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `URL_REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_STORE_ID` (`request_path`,`store_id`),
  KEY `URL_REWRITE_TARGET_PATH` (`target_path`),
  KEY `URL_REWRITE_STORE_ID_ENTITY_ID` (`store_id`,`entity_id`),
  KEY `URL_REWRITE_ENTITY_ID` (`entity_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=145527534 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Url Rewrites' |
```

Note the `UNIQUE KEY` definition in the above output:

```
UNIQUE KEY `URL_REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_STORE_ID` (`request_path`,`store_id`)
```

So, you should also check `store_id` value in your `url_rewrite` table.

For example, if you have this in `url_rewrite` table:

```
request_path = 'my-product'
store_id = 11
```

then, you might get error like:

```
Duplicate entry 'my-product-11' for key 'URL_REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_STORE_ID'
```

This might create confusion if we don't look at the table definition for the unique key.